# VB.net generate a variable for each line in a .txt (nr. of lines unknown)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to generate a variable for each line in a .txt file. It works for the first line but not the ones below. Would be awesome if you guys could help me proceed! This is what I have so far. I was thinking of using EOF but I couldn't get it to work -.-

```
 Dim sr As New StreamReader(cleanfile)
 Dim coins As String() = sr.ReadLine.Split(Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: You want to split each line by `Environment.NewLine`, doesn't make much sense, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of variables must be known at *compile-time*. However, since the number of lines in the file can vary, you don't know this number at compile-time.

Thus, a separate variable for each line is not the solution for your problem.

Your solution is to use an *array*. To create one, you can simply use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(cleanfile)
```

Then, you can access the lines as `lines(0)`, `lines(1)` or iterate through them using the `For Each` statement:

```
For Each line in lines
    ' Do something with line
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: I get the error "ReadAllLines" is no member of "System.IO.StreamWriter". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: By using `File.ReadAllLines(...)` instead of `myStreamWriter.ReadAllLines(...)`. You don't need a StreamWriter nor a StreamReader. If you get a compile error, use the tool tip on `File` to import `System.IO`.

Comment: Stupid me! I used file as a different integer before :) all works now! Thanks a lot!!